# How to format with `gq` using the same settings as when editing the text

Tags: formatting

I have the following options set (in `~/.config/vim/ftplugin/asciidoc.vim`):

```
setlocal wrap
setlocal textwidth=0
setlocal wrapmargin=0
setlocal formatoptions=l
```

And when I'm writing text, it's not hard-wrapped automatically at all.

However, when I need to reformat an existing paragraph, and press `gqap`, it's hard-wrapped to fit 79 columns.

From `help gq`:

```
Format the lines that {motion} moves over.
Formatting is done with one of three methods:

In the third case the 'textwidth' option controls the
length of each formatted line (see below).
If the 'textwidth' option is 0, the formatted line
length is the screen width (with a maximum width of
79).
```

Is there a way to work around this 79 columns limitation?

VIM 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out a negative value for `wrapmargin` helps:

```
setlocal wrapmargin=-1000
```

As per `:help wrapmargin`:

```
Number of characters from the right window border where wrapping
starts.
```

So it seems that the `:help gq` docs are not entirely correct, and with `textwidth=0`, `wrapmargin` is also considered when picking a column to wrap at.